# Download all videos from a Twitch channel

Tags: video, download-manager

I am looking for a program, user script, or web browser extension that can download all videos of a Twitch channel.

https://github.com/Franiac/TwitchLeecher is great to download 1 given video, but cannot download all videos of a Twitch channel (one would need to copypaste all the video URLs or IDs into TwitchLeecher).

Any license, price, web browser and operating system is fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube-DL](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) is a python based command line program, (with a Windows executable also available), which allows downloading videos from various sources, including twitch, (you will probably need to pass your login details in the [.netrc authentication](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#authentication-with-netrc-file).

Among the extractors you can find: twitch:chapter, twitch:clips, twitch:profile, twitch:stream, twitch:video, twitch:videos:all, twitch:videos:highlights, twitch:videos:past-broadcasts, twitch:videos:uploads & twitch:vod

You can download from playlists, channels, etc., and use the [output templates](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template-examples) to organize the files.

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- You can use `--sleep-interval` & `--max-sleep-interval` to avoid problems with the rate limiting that exists on some sites.

Answer (score 1):

To download Twitch clips, [ZeTwitch](https://zetwitch.com/) is a useful tool:

- price: 7 to 9 USD
- videos can easily download in different formats.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65848)